# failed to load webpack.js and main-app.js in Next.js 13 production

Tags: next.js, next.js13

Recently I deployed a Next.js 13 app on server but when I open the app in the browser I get these errors on the console:

[image]

Anyone has an idea what does cause this problem?

Comment: wht version of webpack is used?